# Akka Streams scala DSL and Op-Rabbit

Tags: scala, rabbitmq, akka-stream

I have started using Akka Streams and Op-Rabbit and am a bit confused.

I need to split the stream based on a predicate and then combine them much like I have done when creating graphs and using the Partition and Merge.

I have been able to do things like this using the GraphDSL.Builder, but can't seem to get it to work with AckedSource/Flow/Sink

the graph would look like:

```
                        | --> flow1 --> |
source--> partition --> |               | --> flow3 --> sink
                        | --> flow2 --> |
```

I'm not sure if  splitWhen is what I should use because I always need exactly 2 flows.

This is a sample that does not do the partitioning and does not use the GraphDSL.Builder:

```
def splitExample(source: AckedSource[String, SubscriptionRef],
                 queueName: String)
                (implicit actorSystem: ActorSystem): RunnableGraph[SubscriptionRef] = {
  val toStringFlow: Flow[AckTup[Message], AckTup[String], NotUsed] = Flow[AckTup[Message]]
    .map[AckTup[String]](tup => {
      val (p,m) = tup
      (p, new String(m.data))
    })

  val printFlow1: Flow[AckTup[String], AckTup[String], NotUsed] = Flow[AckTup[String]]
    .map[AckTup[String]](tup => {
      val (p, s) = tup
      println(s"flow1 processing $s")
      tup
     })

  val printFlow2: Flow[AckTup[String], AckTup[String], NotUsed] = Flow[AckTup[String]]
    .map[AckTup[String]](tup => {
      val (p, s) = tup
      println(s"flow2 processing $s")
      tup
    })

  source
    .map(Message.queue(_, queueName))
    .via(AckedFlow(toStringFlow))
    // partition if string.length < 10
    .via(AckedFlow(printFlow1))
    .via(AckedFlow(printFlow2))
    .to(AckedSink.ack)
}
```

This is the code that I can't seem to get working:

```
import GraphDSL.Implicits._
def buildModelAcked(source: AckedSource[String, SubscriptionRef] , queueName: String)(implicit actorSystem: ActorSystem):  Graph[ClosedShape, Future[Done]] = {
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._
    GraphDSL.create(Sink.ignore) { implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[Future[Done]] => s =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._
    source.map(Message.queue(_, queueName)) ~> AckedFlow(toStringFlow) ~> AckedSink.ack
//      source.map(Message.queue(_, queueName)).via(AckedFlow(toStringFlow)).to(AckedSink.ack)
    ClosedShape
```

}}

The compiler can't resolve the `~>` operator

So my questions are:

1. Is there an example project that uses the scala dsl to build graphs of Acked/Source/Flow/Sink?
2. Is there an example project that partitions and merges that is similar to what I am trying to do here?

Comment: Note that in order to get `~>` and other fancy operators, you need to import `GraphDSL.Implicits._` inside the body of the DSL building function.

Comment: Thanks,  I have updated the code to have the import, but alas it still does not resolve the ` ~> ` operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind the following definitions when dealing the [acked-stream](https://github.com/timcharper/acked-stream).

1. `AckedSource[Out, Mat]` is a wrapper for `Source[AckTup[Out], Mat]]`
2. `AckedFlow[In, Out, Mat]` is a wrapper for `Flow[AckTup[In], AckTup[Out], Mat]`
3. `AckedSink[In, Mat]` is a wrapper for `Sink[AckTup[In], Mat]`
4. `AckTup[T]` is an alias for `(Promise[Unit], T)`
5. the classic flow combinators will operate on the `T` part of the `AckTup`
6. the `.acked` combinator will complete the `Promise[Unit]` of an `AckedFlow`

The GraphDSL edge operator (`~>`) will work against a bunch of Akka predefined shapes (see the code for [`GraphDSL.Implicits`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/Graph.scala#L1301)), but it won't work against custom shapes defined by the acked-stream lib.

You got 2 ways out:

1. you define your own `~>` implicit operator, along the lines of the ones in `GraphDSL.Implicits`
2. you unwrap the acked stages to obtain standard stages. You are able to access the wrapped stage using `.wrappedRepr` - available on `AckedSource`, `AckedFlow` and `AckedSink`.

Comment: This is the code I can't seem to get working:
 `def buildModelAcked(source: AckedSource[String, SubscriptionRef] , queueName: String)(implicit actorSystem: ActorSystem):  Graph[ClosedShape, Future[Done]] = {
       GraphDSL.create(Sink.ignore) { implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[Future[Done]] => s =>
       //  source.map(Message.queue(_, queueName)) ~> AckedFlow(toStringFlow) ~> AckedSink.ack
       source.map(Message.queue(_, queueName)).via(AckedFlow(toStringFlow)).to(AckedSink.ack)
      ClosedShape
    }}
works w/o dsl, but can't resolve the ~> operator

Comment: could you give me a simple example?
Thanks

Comment: Excellent!  That was the missing piece.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on Stefano Bonetti's excellent direction, here is a possible solution:

```
graph:    
                        |--> short --|
  rabbitMq --> before --|            |--> after
                        |--> long  --|
```

solution:

```
val before: Flow[AckTup[Message], AckTup[String], NotUsed] = Flow[AckTup[Message]].map[AckTup[String]](tup => {
  val (p,m) = tup
  (p, new String(m.data))
})

val short: Flow[AckTup[String], AckTup[String], NotUsed] = Flow[AckTup[String]].map[AckTup[String]](tup => {
  val (p, s) = tup
  println(s"short: $s")
  tup
})
val long: Flow[AckTup[String], AckTup[String], NotUsed] = Flow[AckTup[String]].map[AckTup[String]](tup => {
  val (p, s) = tup
  println(s"long: $s")
  tup
})
val after: Flow[AckTup[String], AckTup[String], NotUsed] = Flow[AckTup[String]].map[AckTup[String]](tup => {
  val (p, s) = tup
  println(s"all $s")
  tup
})

def buildSplitGraph(source: AckedSource[String, SubscriptionRef]
                    , queueName: String
                    , splitLength: Int)(implicit actorSystem: ActorSystem):  Graph[ClosedShape, Future[Done]] = {
 GraphDSL.create(Sink.ignore) { implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[Future[Done]] => s =>
   val toShort = 0
   val toLong = 1

   // junctions
   val split = builder.add(Partition[AckTup[String]](2, (tup: AckTup[String]) => {
                                                           val (p, s) = tup
                                                           if (s.length < splitLength) toShort else toLong
                                                         }
   ))
   val merge = builder.add(Merge[AckTup[String]](2))

   //graph
   val beforeSplit = source.map(Message.queue(_, queueName)).wrappedRepr ~> AckedFlow(before).wrappedRepr
   beforeSplit ~> split
   // must do short, then long since the split goes in that order
   split ~> AckedFlow(short).wrappedRepr ~> merge
   split ~> AckedFlow(long).wrappedRepr ~> merge
   // after the last AckedFlow, be sure to '.acked' so that the message will be removed from the queue
   merge ~> AckedFlow(after).acked ~> s

  ClosedShape
}}
```

As Stefano Bonetti said, the key was to use the `.wrappedRepr` associated with the `AckedFlow` and then to use the `.acked` combinator as the last step.